# Spring boot hibernate application throws Negative revision numbers are not allowed when inserting

Tags: spring, audit

I have taken a DB dump from my dev database to QA database ( oracle) for testing. My application is  a spring boot application and uses hibernate envers for auditing. I get above error when trying to insert data to the tables. I tried removing data from all the audit tables and revinfo table. But the issue is still there. Anybody has any idea on this?

Comment: We ran into the same issue. In our case it was caused by a number overflow: the Id column on the audit log entity was mapped to an Integer, and the database sequence was too high causing it to go negative when cast to an Integer.

Answer (score 2):

Same error after updating the version of hibernate-envers for springboot3+. One quick solution for me was to (first backup) remove all tables related to audit + remove revinfo table and also the sequencer (revinfo_seq if you created some). Then let the ddl-auto property do the work by setting in application.yml

```
jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

It creates all needed tables and sequencers by its needed definition, and after that inserts were committed.